# How to I obtain the iso for Ubuntu for virtual box?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, iso

I'm having trouble finding the ISO for my Ubuntu download. Where should I go to obtain it?

Comment: You can find downloads at [Ubuntu's Website](http://www.ubuntu.com)

Answer (score 2):

On the official download page:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download